# Разбить число на разряды

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется переменная, которая принимает разные значения: от 0 до "много-много"(12358964). Как сделать, чтобы оно разбивалось на тысячи, десятки тысяч, сотни тысяч, миллионы и т.д.? Т.е., 10.000, 1.000, 12.358.964.

```
balance.text = int sum;
update.text = int income;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы не поверите — но это задача обычного `.ToString()`:

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание — что в разных странах приняты свои разделители и указывая языковую культуру вы можете управлять и настраивать поведение разделителей.

Например в русской локали разделитель — пробел:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", culture));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в немецкой — точки, как вы и хотели:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", culture));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А можно и в русской локали [переопределить](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=netcore-2.0) один параметр — и будет вам разделитель точкой, а все остальные параметры - как в русской локали по умолчанию:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU")
{
    NumberFormat =
    {
        NumberGroupSeparator = ".",
    },
};

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,#", culture));
```

Почитайте подробнее про форматирование чисел в документации:

- [Строки настраиваемых числовых форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)- мой пример как раз отсюда
- [Типы форматирования в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types) - обзорный материал по форматированию

Comment: Правда в вопросе было с точками...

Comment: @VerNick Сейчас, поищу ещё локаль с точками или найду какой там параметр переопределить.

Comment: @VerNick Готово.